# Modify reactjs form input value outside of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, browser

I'm using a js lib that uses react under the hood. I want to modify it to prefill an input on a form that it renders. I only have access to the top level react component from instantiation. How can I set the value such that react picks it up?

I've tried setting `el.value` and `$el.attr('value', 'val')` to no avail. I've also tried setting the state directly with `el.__reactInternalInstance$abc123._currentElement.props.value` but doesn't work either.

Calling:

```
const event = new Event("input", { bubbles: true })
el.dispatchEvent(event)
```

hasn't helped either.

Comment: did you find a way ?

Comment: i did, just added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution using jquery, couldn't get it to work without a library. The first line fills the field when the user clicks the input. The second fills it when they expand operation. Note that one gets called on expanding any operation. But jquery seems to work just fine with `on` click. Part of the problem is that the elements are created until the operation is expanded.

```
$('body').on('click', 'tr[data-param-name="<INPUT NAME>"] input', setInput)
$('.opblock').on('click', setInput)
```

I don't have the link for where I found the below call but this seems to set the value in a way that gets picked up by react.

```
    function setInput (e) {
        let xinput = $('tr[data-param-name="<INPUT NAME>"] input')
        let target = xinput[0]
        if (xinput.val() == '') {
            let value = "INPUT VALUE"
            const setter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, "value").set
            const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(target)
            const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(prototype, 'value').set
            if (setter && setter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
                prototypeValueSetter.call(target, value)
            } else {
                setter.call(target, value)
            }
            const event = new Event("input", {bubbles: true})
            target.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: mine only worked with that input event after setting the innerHTML of a contentEditable div. Didn't have to call the setter manually.